# trying to calculate distance between points, keep getting incorrect output

Tags: python

```
import math

point_dist = 0.0

x1 = float(input())
y1 = float(input())
x2 = float(input())
y2 = float(input())

point_dist = math.pow(math.sqrt(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1), 2.0)

print('Points distance:', point_dist)
```

here is what I have written so far, keeps giving me incorrect numbers for output

input: 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.0

expected output: 9.0

what im getting: 3.0

Comment: Your inputs and expected outputs would be helpful...

Comment: just edited the post

Comment: the correct answer is 3? (1, 2) to (1, 5) is a displacement of 3 along y???

Comment: sorry I am new here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`math.dist` can do this for you.

```py
import math

point_dist = 0.0

x1 = float(input())
y1 = float(input())
x2 = float(input())
y2 = float(input())

point_dist = math.dist((x1, y1), (x2, y2))

print('Points distance:', point_dist)
```

Note that the distance between (1, 2) and (1, 5) *is* 3.

Answer (score 2):

Use the correct formula for distance:

```
point_dist = ((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)**0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is simply wrong.
Should be changed like this:

```py
point_dist = math.sqrt(math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + math.pow(y2 - y1, 2))
```